# Add laravel code to jsPDF

Tags: javascript, laravel, jspdf

I understand how [jspdf](/questions/tagged/jspdf) work when adding text.

I used the `doc.text(20,20,'Hello World')` and this works

However I want to add predetermined text set by the user. When calling this text in PHP I use something like this: `{{$campaign->short_description}}`

However when I write this line of code: `doc.text({{$campaign->short_description}})` then the download button doesn't allow you to generate and download the PDF, simply nothing happens when clicked.

How can I add text such as `{{$campaign->short_description}}` with [jspdf](/questions/tagged/jspdf)?

Comment: Is there any logging output in your console? And could you please include some more of the javascript you use to generate the pdf?

Comment: Something people often miss is that including this code as a pure `.js` file (linked via `<script src="...">`) won't allow the use of PHP syntax. Is your file a `.blade.php` file using a `<script>` tag? That's the only way you'll be able to inject PHP (Blade) syntax `{{ $example }}` into a JS `doc.text()` function.

Comment: why is this question so hated on? Helped me thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.text({{$campaign->short_description}})` is going to generate something like `doc.text(A short description!)`, which is going to be invalid JavaScript.

You need something like `doc.text('A short description!')`, but you're also going to need to handle things like `'` characters in the descriptions.

Thankfully, PHP has a function that will do this perfectly for JavaScript - `json_encode`. It'll happily output strings, complex objects, etc. in a JS-friendly manner.

```
doc.text({!! json_encode($campaign->short_description) !!});
```

Comment: `doc.text('{{$campaign->short_description}}')` (single quotes around `blade` braces) should work too. Kinda depends what `$campaign->short_description` contains though.

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah, that's why I recommend `json_encode` - it'll correctly escape any special characters in a JS-friendly manner. A description of `Bob's article` would give your approach a parse error.

Comment: this didn't work for me ended up getting what I needed from DOM-selectors